# C++11 std::thread and virtual function binding

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, race-condition

I ran into a weird C++ code behaviour, not sure whether it's a compiler bug or simply undefined/unspecified behaviour of my code. Here is the code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

struct Parent {
    std::thread t;

    static void entry(Parent* p) {
        p->init();
        p->fini();
    }

    virtual ~Parent() { t.join(); }

    void start() { t = std::thread{entry, this}; }

    virtual void init() { std::cout << "Parent::init()" << std::endl; }
    virtual void fini() { std::cout << "Parent::fini()" << std::endl; }
};

struct Child : public Parent {
    virtual void init() override { std::cout << "Child::init()" << std::endl; }
    virtual void fini() override { std::cout << "Child::fini()" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    Child c;

    c.start();
    sleep(1); // <========== here is it

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the code would be the following, which isn't surprising:

```
Child::init()
Child::fini()
```

However, if the function call "sleep(1)" is commented out, the output would be:

```
Parent::init()
Parent::~fini()
```

Tested on Ubuntu 15.04, both gcc-4.9.2 and clang-3.6.0 show the same behaviour. Compiler options:

```
g++/clang++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -pthread
```

It looks like a race condition (the vtable not fully constructed before the thread starts). Is this code ill-formed ? a compiler bug ? or it's supposed to be like this ?

Comment: Think about it: The thread uses the child object, but the child object is destroyed *before* the thread is joined (because the joining only happens after the destruction of the child has begun)!

Comment: With sleep commented, you "call" virtual method inside destructor...

Comment: A quick fix would be to create a destructor for Child and call `t.join();` from there. You'd have to make your thread protected but then again I did say it was a quick fix.

Comment: @KerrekSB Has give you the right answer. By the way, the fact that in your computer you see the child functions due to the sleep is misleading; other computers could still see the `Parent` functions called or `Child` then `Parent`.

Comment: @MohamadElghawi That will cause `join()` to be called twice. The destructor should therefore check if `t` is joinable before doing so.

Comment: @bku_drytt I meant calling it from ~Child and removing it from ~Parent. Not elegant but a quick fix.

Comment: *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think, "I know, I'll use threads," and then ththen theey hyhaveave two probletwo problemsms.*

Comment: This design issue is a fundamental threading issue, with nothing specific about `std::thread`, vtables, vptrs...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*@KerrekSB commented:*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33172001/c11-stdthread-and-virtual-function-binding#comment54151629_33172001)

> **”**  The thread uses the child object, but the child object is destroyed before the thread is joined (because the joining only happens after the destruction of the child has begun).

The `Child` object is destroyed at the end of `main`. The `Child` destructor is executed, and effectively calls the `Parent` destructor, where `Parent` bases (no such) and data members (the thread object) are destroyed. As destructors are invoked up the chain of base classes the **dynamic type** of the object changes, in reverse order of how it changes during construction, so at this point the type of the object is `Parent`.

The virtual calls in the thread function can happen before, overlapping with or after the call of the `Child` destructor, and in the case of overlapping there's one thread accessing storage (in practice, the vtable pointer) that is being changed by another thread. So this is Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score -1):

This is common design issue; what you tried to do is a classical anti-pattern.

`Parent` cannot be at the same time a thread manager, starting a thread and waiting for thread termination:

```
virtual ~Parent() { t.join(); }

void start() { t = std::thread{entry, this}; }
```

and also a thread object:

```
virtual void init() { std::cout << "Parent::init()" << std::endl; }
virtual void fini() { std::cout << "Parent::fini()" << std::endl; }
```

These are two distinct concepts, with strictly incompatible specifications.

(And thread objects are not useful in general.)

Comment: Do you have usefull pattern to suggest solving this particular problem ?